# How to import browser console and retain backwards compatibility?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Firefox 44 is changing the way the browser console is imported (as seen in [bug 1203159](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1203159)). Based on the latest browser compatibility checks, my understanding is that the following import directive will no longer work:

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');
```

Based on the information in the bug, the new URL will be:

```
Components.utils.import('resource://devtools/Console.jsm');
```

However, this path apparently doesn't work in current versions of Firefox. What is the best way for a Firefox extension to use the upcoming resource path while maintaining compatibility with current versions? Is there a way I can attempt to import one path, and if it fails, attempt to load the other one?

Comment: I was under the impression that it was moved from `resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm` to `resource://gre/modules/Console.jsm`.  I modified four of my extensions, validated them on AMO Developer Hub, submitted them and they were approved.  Are you sure the new url is `resource://devtools/Console.jsm`?

Comment: In fact, `resource://devtools/Console.jsm` is not even a valid url when pasted into the location bar of Fx 45.0a2 (while the other two _are_ valid).

Comment: I asked over at [Mozilla Discourse](https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/devtools-location-change/6617) and according to [Mozilla Cross-reference](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=console.jsm), the correct location is `resource://gre/modules/Console.jsm`.

Comment: Interesting. I guess I misread the bug. Thanks for the proper path.

Comment: The notice did say `Error: The paths for all devtools JS modules have changed from resource://gre/modules/devtools/* to resource://devtools/*.See https://bugzil.la/1203159 for more information.` which turned out to be incorrect ;)

Comment: Seems to me this should be reported to Mozilla. I have no idea where to do that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a few developers using `try {} catch {}` statements

```
try { Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm'); }
catch { Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Console.jsm'); }
```

**Note:** Contrary to the Mozilla notice (below), I found out that the new location for `Services.jsm` is `resource://gre/modules/Console.jsm`

Mozilla Notice:

> Error: The paths for all devtools JS modules have changed from
>   resource://gre/modules/devtools/* to resource://devtools/*.See
>   https://bugzil.la/1203159 for more information.